# How to add attributes to database columns

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, peewee

Im currently working on creating correct database columns for my database. I have created two tables and used alter:

```
CREATE TABLE stores (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    store_name TEXT
    -- add more fields if needed
);


CREATE TABLE products (
    id SERIAL, 
    store_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    title TEXT,
    image TEXT,
    url TEXT UNIQUE, 
    added_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    PRIMARY KEY(id, store_id)
);


ALTER TABLE products
ADD  CONSTRAINT "FK_products_stores" FOREIGN KEY ("store_id")
        REFERENCES stores (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Now I am trying to use it together with [PeeWee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) and I have managed to do a small step which is:

```
class Stores(Model):
    id = IntegerField(column_name='id')
    store_id = TextField(column_name='store_name')

class Products(Model):
    id = IntegerField(column_name='id')
    store_id = IntegerField(column_name='store_id')
    title = TextField(column_name='title')
    url = TextField(column_name='url')
    image = TextField(column_name='image')
```

However my problem is that I have used:

```
ALTER TABLE products
ADD  CONSTRAINT "FK_products_stores" FOREIGN KEY ("store_id")
        REFERENCES stores (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

which means that I do have a Foreign key and I am quite not sure how I can apply to use Foreign key together with PeeWee. I wonder how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `ForeignKeyField` to `Products` and remove `store_id`

```py
class Products(Model):
    id = IntegerField(column_name='id')
    title = TextField(column_name='title')
    url = TextField(column_name='url')
    image = TextField(column_name='image')
    store = ForeignKeyField(Stores, backref='products')
```

Comment: Ahhh make sense! and now if I want to do a select or insert, what would be the difference now compare to not settings a ForeignKey in the Products(Model)?

Comment: without the FK field, you'd need to specify the relationship in your joins, like `Products.select().join(Store, on=(Products.store_id == Store.id))`

Comment: Ohhh okey so now I would just need to do something like `Products.select().join(store)` instead?

Comment: you might not even need to join since the relationship is already defined. The [doc](https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/relationships.html) has some good examples

Comment: Thanks! Apprecaite the help! Well deserved answer!